# Looking for textbook publisher which allows teachers to modify e-books before publishing

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a website I once saw which allowed university textbook authors to publish their works as e-books but then teachers could buy the book for their class but could also add or delete chapters and add and delete the original text at the paragraph level, then republish it as a derivative book that the students of their class could buy online and have have printed at the university copy shop.

Does anyone know which website this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://create.mcgraw-hill.com/wordpress-mu/welcomeprimisuser/

McGraw-Hill CREATE allows you to upload your material and combine it with McGraw-Hill content. Good luck!